# How to set CardView background color with .background()?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm following the SwiftUI tutorial at https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/displaying-data-in-a-list

Running the project's sample download files, I can see the CardView includes the correct background color with this code:

```
        CardView(scrum: scrum)
            .background(scrum.theme.mainColor)
```

It looks like this (it works):
[image: sample code with working preview]

For whatever reason, I have copied *ALL* of the code exactly as-is from Apple's sample file into my local Project, and I do not get a background color.

My local Xcode project looks like this (no background color even though exact same code):

[image: same code but preview does not work]

I understand the simple code conceptually. There is a DailyScrum model object that has an attribute Theme. The Theme enum has a `mainColor`. This `mainColor` is passed to the CardView `.background()`.

So I don't understand if this is an Xcode issue, a config file issue, a simulator issue, or a Scheme (to run iPhone Simulator) issue. I have no idea why running the exact same SwiftUI code in two different Xcode projects results in 1 with a working preview and another without a working preview. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

In the downloadable sample project from Apple, there is an Assets folder with named colors in Themes. This needs to be created so the named colors can be found.

[image: named colors in Themes]

Answer (score 1):

Do you read the tutorials carefully? Apple says that all of that colors are in the starter project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A little more input to your problem...
The use of the .background() modifier needs a content inside your Assets folder or an View and the declaration shows us it will return a view, important to know.

Lets take a look in the **Declaration**.

```
func background<Background>(
    _ background: Background,
    alignment: Alignment = .center
) -> some View where Background : View
```

**What is possible to do with the .background modifier?**

You can now use an image like you did. This could be a single colour, but also an image of a city, bagles or whatever. The cooler thing the .background modifier offers us are the views you can insert and play around with.

Lets say you want a Rectangle behind an Folder-systemimage.

You would now create a struct, build your background in it and pass this struct inside your Image, as an background. I'll show you an example from apple.

```
//here you can find your struct what currently shows the Rectangle background
struct DiamondBackground: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.gray)
                .frame(width: 250, height: 250, alignment: .center)
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(45.0))
        }
    }
}


struct Frontmost: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            //here is your image - in this case its a simple systemimage (can found in SFSymbols)
            Image(systemName: "folder")
                .font(.system(size: 128, weight: .ultraLight))
                .background(DiamondBackground())
                //here is the .background modifier with your selfmade DiamondBackground struct 
        }
    }
}
```

This example looks like this now:

[image]